# Is there a way to set minimum blocksize in FTP python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to retrieve date from mainframe using Python.

I'm using the below code to get the desired result:

```
ST_server.retrbinary('RETR filename', prntfun, blocksize=6205)
```

However, I want the code to always retrieve data as per the `blocksize` mentioned in the `retrbinary` statement (i.e to get 6205 bytes after every callback function). But looks like, `blocksize` is dynamically changed which is not what I want.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean the block size of the mainframe system. While the `blocksize` argument of `FTP.retrbinary` is about local buffer used for reading the data from a socket.

With FTP protocol, you can set the mainframe block size using `SITE` command.

See IBM documentation for [SIte subcommand—Send site-specific information to a host](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/latest?topic=subcommands-site-subcommandsend-site-specific-information-host).

I cannot test, but something like this should do:

```
ftp.sendcmd("SITE BLKsize=6205")
```